# Tate-Shafarevich group is trivial?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $A$ be an abelian variety. Then $k \mapsto H^1(k,A)$ is a functor. Therefore the injection $k \to k_\nu$ induces an injection $H^1(k,A) \to H^1(k_v,A)$. This means that the Tate-Shafarevich group is trivial. What went wrong?

Comment: A functor doesn't necessarily preserve injection.

Comment: Function $f$ is an injection if and only if it has a left inverse. So $g \circ f = I$ for some $g$. By the definition of functor (F) we have $F(g) \circ F(f) = I$ meaning that $F(f)$ has a left inverse so that it is injection

Comment: But the left inverse of $k\to k_\nu$ isn't a morphism of rings, am I missing something ?

Comment: Great. That solves it.